# How many Pokemon can be obtained only in Emerald?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

How many Pokemon can one have in Pokemon Emerald, assuming no trading with other games, no special event Pokemon, no cheat devices, and no exploiting [arbitrary code execution glitches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pb-6hMDQBs)?

In other words, if one were to be locked alone in a room with only a GBA and Emerald cartridge and as much time as they need to play, how many unique Pokemon could be legitimately obtained?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Major rewrite from the [first revision](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/331103/revisions), but I've calculated it all manually:

## Pokemon Emerald National Pokedex Total: 212/386

Without trades, access to event-exclusive items and Pokemon, Mystery Gift, or an E-reader (Pokemon functionality of which is Japanese-cart exclusive), the best you can do is 212 Pokemon.

If you're willing to perform duplicate item glitches - you can bump this up to 213 by duplicating the Moon Stone - but I wouldn't count this as 'legitimately obtained'

#### Notable Obtainable Pokemon

- One of *Latios* and *Latias* are obtainable - (one will be roaming and one will be on Southern Island). After the Elite 4 a news broadcast will report on a Roaming Pokemon. Speak to your mother - the answer you give to her will determine which is available - 'Blue' for Latios, 'Red' for Latias.
- Both *Groudon* and *Kyogre* are obtainable after the Elite Four - a researcher in the Weather Institute will talk about severe weather happening on a particular Route. If it's Harsh Sunlight, look for a newly formed cave. If it's torrential rain, look for a newly formed trench of water that you can Dive into.
- *Sudowoodo* is 'hiding' in the Battle Frontier. Just like Gen 2, use the Watering Pail on the 'tree' to start the encounter.
- The fossil that disappears from Mirage tower when you take the other one is also available post-Elite Four in the '[Desert Underpass](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Desert_Underpass)'
- *Meowth* is a Trade NPC exclusive Pokemon - trade for Skitty at the Battle Frontier
- *Beldum* is left for the player in Steven's house in Mossdeep City.
- *Wynaut* hatches from the Egg given to you by the Old Lady in Lavaridge Town
- *Feebas* evolves into *Milotic* via Level up with high Beauty (in most later games Milotic is only obtainable via trade).

#### Pokemon locked by Trade

- The 7 Ruby/Sapphire exclusive Pokemon are: *Surskit*, *Masquerain*, *Meditite*, *Medicham*, *Roselia*, *Zangoose* and *Lunatone*
- The following Pokemon have prior evolutions available but require a trade to evolve into themselves: *Alakazam*, *Golem*, *Machamp*, *Politoed*, *Kingdra*, *Huntail*, *Gorebyss*
- Without trading, you'll be unable to complete the Regional Pokedex, and therefore will be unable to get a Generation 2 starter (*Chikorita*, *Totodile*, *Cyndaquil*) from Professor Elm.
- There is only one Moon Stone to find on the map, and no wild Pokemon that hold them, so you have to choose between evolving *Skitty* into *Delcatty*, or *Jigglypuff* into *Wigglytuff*

#### Pokemon locked by Event:

- *Jirachi*, *Celebi*, *Mew*, *Deoxys*, *Lugia* and *Ho-oh* are 'technically' obtainable in-game, but you need event-exclusive items to get to them.
- The other *Latios* / *Latias* that isn't roaming will be on Southern Island, you'll need the Eon Ticket - which is only obtainable using an E-reader with the physical 'Eon Ticket' card, or mixing records with another trainer that has done so.
- Surskit and Masquerain CAN be found in Emerald via [Outbreaks (Swarms)](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_outbreak)... but only after '[Record Mixing](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Record_mixing)' with a Ruby or Sapphire game.

### Raw Data

Here's the raw data I've compiled:

```
#   Name    Obtainable  Method/Reason
1   Bulbasaur   No      Trade
2   Ivysaur     No      Trade
3   Venusaur    No      Trade
4   Charmander  No      Trade
5   Charmeleon  No      Trade
6   Charizard   No      Trade
7   Squirtle    No      Trade
8   Wartortle   No      Trade
9   Blastoise   No      Trade
10  Caterpie    No      Trade
11  Metapod     No      Trade
12  Butterfree  No      Trade
13  Weedle      No      Trade
14  Kakuna      No      Trade
15  Beedrill    No      Trade
16  Pidgey      No      Trade
17  Pidgeotto   No      Trade
18  Pidgeot     No      Trade
19  Rattata     No      Trade
20  Raticate    No      Trade
21  Spearow     No      Trade
22  Fearow      No      Trade
23  Ekans       No      Trade
24  Arbok       No      Trade
25  Pikachu     Yes     Catch
26  Raichu      Yes     Evolve
27  Sandshrew   Yes     Catch
28  Sandslash   Yes     Evolve
29  Nidoran-F   No      Trade
30  Nidorina    No      Trade
31  Nidoqueen   No      Trade
32  Nidoran-M   No      Trade
33  Nidorino    No      Trade
34  Nidoking    No      Trade
35  Clefairy    No      Trade
36  Clefable    No      Trade
37  Vulpix      Yes     Catch
38  Ninetales   Yes     Evolve
39  Jigglypuff  Yes     Catch
40  Wigglytuff  Yes     Evolve - Only 1 Moon Stone (Delcatty or Wigglytuff)
41  Zubat       Yes     Catch
42  Golbat      Yes     Catch,Evolve
43  Oddish      Yes     Catch
44  Gloom       Yes     Catch,Evolve
45  Vileplume   Yes     Evolve
46  Paras       No      Trade
47  Parasect    No      Trade
48  Venonat     No      Trade
49  Venomoth    No      Trade
50  Diglett     No      Trade
51  Dugtrio     No      Trade
52  Meowth      Yes     Trade NPC
53  Persian     Yes     Evolve
54  Psyduck     Yes     Catch
55  Golduck     Yes     Catch,Evolve
56  Mankey      No      Trade
57  Primeape    No      Trade
58  Growlithe   No      Trade
59  Arcanine    No      Trade
60  Poliwag     No      Trade
61  Poliwhirl   No      Trade
62  Poliwrath   No      Trade
63  Abra        Yes     Catch
64  Kadabra     Yes     Evolve
65  Alakazam    No      Trade Evo
66  Machop      Yes     Catch
67  Machoke     Yes     Evolve
68  Machamp     No      Trade Evo
69  Bellsprout  No      Trade
70  Weepinbell  No      Trade
71  Victreebel  No      Trade
72  Tentacool   Yes     Catch
73  Tentacruel  Yes     Catch,Evolve
74  Geodude     Yes     Catch
75  Graveler    Yes     Catch,Evolve
76  Golem       No      Trade Evo
77  Ponyta      No      Trade
78  Rapidash    No      Trade
79  Slowpoke    No      Trade
80  Slowbro     No      Trade
81  Magnemite   Yes     Catch
82  Magneton    Yes     Catch,Evolve
83  Farfetchd   No      Trade
84  Doduo       Yes     Catch
85  Dodrio      Yes     Catch,Evolve
86  Seel        No      Trade
87  Dewgong     No      Trade
88  Grimer      Yes     Catch
89  Muk         Yes     Evolve
90  Shellder    No      Trade
91  Cloyster    No      Trade
92  Gastly      No      Trade
93  Haunter     No      Trade
94  Gengar      No      Trade
95  Onix        No      Trade
96  Drowzee     No      Trade
97  Hypno       No      Trade
98  Krabby      No      Trade
99  Kingler     No      Trade
100 Voltorb     Yes     Catch
101 Electrode   Yes     Catch,Evolve
102 Exeggcute   No      Trade
103 Exeggutor   No      Trade
104 Cubone      No      Trade
105 Marowak     No      Trade
106 Hitmonlee   No      Trade
107 Hitmonchan  No      Trade
108 Lickitung   No      Trade
109 Koffing     Yes     Catch
110 Weezing     Yes     Evolve
111 Rhyhorn     Yes     Catch
112 Rhydon      Yes     Evolve
113 Chansey     No      Trade
114 Tangela     No      Trade
115 Kangaskhan  No      Trade
116 Horsea      Yes     Catch
117 Seadra      Yes     Evolve
118 Goldeen     Yes     Catch
119 Seaking     Yes     Catch,Evolve
120 Staryu      Yes     Catch
121 Starmie     Yes     Evolve
122 Mr-Mime     No      Trade
123 Scyther     No      Trade
124 Jynx        No      Trade
125 Electabuzz  No      Trade
126 Magmar      No      Trade
127 Pinsir      Yes     Catch
128 Tauros      No      Trade
129 Magikarp    Yes     Catch
130 Gyarados    Yes     Catch,Evolve
131 Lapras      No      Trade
132 Ditto       Yes     Catch
133 Eevee       No      Trade
134 Vaporeon    No      Trade
135 Jolteon     No      Trade
136 Flareon     No      Trade
137 Porygon     No      Trade
138 Omanyte     No      Trade
139 Omastar     No      Trade
140 Kabuto      No      Trade
141 Kabutops    No      Trade
142 Aerodactyl  No      Trade
143 Snorlax     No      Trade
144 Articuno    No      Trade
145 Zapdos      No      Trade
146 Moltres     No      Trade
147 Dratini     No      Trade
148 Dragonair   No      Trade
149 Dragonite   No      Trade
150 Mewtwo      No      Trade
151 Mew         No      Event Item required (Japan only)
152 Chikorita   No      Trade, Complete Regional Dex
153 Bayleef     No      Trade
154 Meganium    No      Trade
155 Cyndaquil   No      Trade, Complete Regional Dex
156 Quilava     No      Trade
157 Typhlosion  No      Trade
158 Totodile    No      Trade, Complete Regional Dex
159 Croconaw    No      Trade
160 Feraligatr  No      Trade
161 Sentret     No      Trade
162 Furret      No      Trade
163 Hoothoot    Yes     Catch
164 Noctowl     Yes     Evolve
165 Ledyba      Yes     Catch
166 Ledian      Yes     Evolve
167 Spinarak    Yes     Catch
168 Ariados     Yes     Evolve
169 Crobat      Yes     Evolve
170 Chinchou    Yes     Catch
171 Lanturn     Yes     Evolve
172 Pichu       Yes     Breed
173 Cleffa      No      Trade
174 Igglybuff   Yes     Breed
175 Togepi      No      Trade
176 Togetic     No      Trade
177 Natu        Yes     Catch
178 Xatu        Yes     Catch,Evolve
179 Mareep      Yes     Catch
180 Flaaffy     Yes     Evolve
181 Ampharos    Yes     Evolve
182 Bellossom   Yes     Evolve
183 Marill      Yes     Catch
184 Azumarill   Yes     Evolve
185 Sudowoodo   Yes     Catch
186 Politoed    No      Trade,Trade Evo
187 Hoppip      No      Trade
188 Skiploom    No      Trade
189 Jumpluff    No      Trade
190 Aipom       Yes     Catch
191 Sunkern     Yes     Catch
192 Sunflora    Yes     Evolve
193 Yanma       No      Trade
194 Wooper      Yes     Catch
195 Quagsire    Yes     Catch,Evolve
196 Espeon      No      Trade
197 Umbreon     No      Trade
198 Murkrow     No      Trade
199 Slowking    No      Trade
200 Misdreavus  No      Trade
201 Unown       No      Trade
202 Wobbuffet   Yes     Catch
203 Girafarig   Yes     Catch
204 Pineco      Yes     Catch
205 Forretress  Yes     Evolve
206 Dunsparce   No      Trade
207 Gligar      Yes     Catch
208 Steelix     No      Trade
209 Snubbull    Yes     Catch
210 Granbull    Yes     Evolve
211 Qwilfish    No      Trade
212 Scizor      No      Trade
213 Shuckle     Yes     Catch
214 Heracross   Yes     Catch
215 Sneasel     No      Trade
216 Teddiursa   Yes     Catch
217 Ursaring    Yes     Evolve
218 Slugma      Yes     Catch
219 Magcargo    Yes     Evolve
220 Swinub      No      Trade
221 Piloswine   No      Trade
222 Corsola     Yes     Catch
223 Remoraid    Yes     Catch
224 Octillery   Yes     Catch,Evolve
225 Delibird    No      Trade
226 Mantine     No      Trade
227 Skarmory    Yes     Catch
228 Houndour    Yes     Catch
229 Houndoom    Yes     Evolve
230 Kingdra     No      Trade Evo
231 Phanpy      Yes     Catch
232 Donphan     Yes     Evolve
233 Porygon2    No      Trade,Trade Evo
234 Stantler    Yes     Catch
235 Smeargle    Yes     Catch
236 Tyrogue     No      Trade
237 Hitmontop   No      Trade
238 Smoochum    No      Trade
239 Elekid      No      Trade
240 Magby       No      Trade
241 Miltank     Yes     Catch
242 Blissey     No      Trade
243 Raikou      No      Trade
244 Entei       No      Trade
245 Suicune     No      Trade
246 Larvitar    No      Trade
247 Pupitar     No      Trade
248 Tyranitar   No      Trade
249 Lugia       No      Event Item required
250 Ho-Oh       No      Event Item required
251 Celebi      No      Trade, Event
252 Treecko     Yes     Starter - 1 evo line only
253 Grovyle     Yes     Starter - 1 evo line only
254 Sceptile    Yes     Starter - 1 evo line only
255 Torchic     No      Starter - 1 evo line only
256 Combusken   No      Starter - 1 evo line only
257 Blaziken    No      Starter - 1 evo line only
258 Mudkip      No      Starter - 1 evo line only
259 Marshtomp   No      Starter - 1 evo line only
260 Swampert    No      Starter - 1 evo line only
261 Poochyena   Yes     Catch
262 Mightyena   Yes     Catch,Evolve
263 Zigzagoon   Yes     Catch
264 Linoone     Yes     Catch,Evolve
265 Wurmple     Yes     Catch
266 Silcoon     Yes     Catch,Evolve
267 Beautifly   Yes     Evolve
268 Cascoon     Yes     Catch,Evolve
269 Dustox      Yes     Evolve
270 Lotad       Yes     Catch
271 Lombre      Yes     Catch,Evolve
272 Ludicolo    Yes     Evolve
273 Seedot      Yes     Catch
274 Nuzleaf     Yes     Catch,Evolve
275 Shiftry     Yes     Evolve
276 Taillow     Yes     Catch
277 Swellow     Yes     Catch,Evolve
278 Wingull     Yes     Catch
279 Pelipper    Yes     Catch,Evolve
280 Ralts       Yes     Catch
281 Kirlia      Yes     Evolve
282 Gardevoir   Yes     Evolve
283 Surskit     No      Swarm - Only after record mixing with Ruby/Sapphire
284 Masquerain  No      Evolve
285 Shroomish   Yes     Catch
286 Breloom     Yes     Evolve
287 Slakoth     Yes     Catch
288 Vigoroth    Yes     Evolve
289 Slaking     Yes     Evolve
290 Nincada     Yes     Catch
291 Ninjask     Yes     Evolve
292 Shedinja    Yes     Evolve
293 Whismur     Yes     Catch
294 Loudred     Yes     Catch,Evolve
295 Exploud     Yes     Evolve
296 Makuhita    Yes     Catch
297 Hariyama    Yes     Catch,Evolve
298 Azurill     Yes     Breed Marill holding Sea Incense
299 Nosepass    Yes     Catch
300 Skitty      Yes     Catch
301 Delcatty    No      Evolve - Only 1 Moon Stone (Delcatty or Wigglytuff)
302 Sableye     Yes     Catch
303 Mawile      Yes     Catch
304 Aron        Yes     Catch
305 Lairon      Yes     Catch,Evolve
306 Aggron      Yes     Evolve
307 Meditite    No      Trade
308 Medicham    No      Trade
309 Electrike   Yes     Catch
310 Manectric   Yes     Catch,Evolve
311 Plusle      Yes     Catch, Trade NPC
312 Minun       Yes     Catch
313 Volbeat     Yes     Catch
314 Illumise    Yes     Catch
315 Roselia     No      Trade
316 Gulpin      Yes     Catch
317 Swalot      Yes     Evolve
318 Carvanha    Yes     Catch
319 Sharpedo    Yes     Catch,Evolve
320 Wailmer     Yes     Catch
321 Wailord     Yes     Catch,Evolve
322 Numel       Yes     Catch
323 Camerupt    Yes     Evolve
324 Torkoal     Yes     Catch
325 Spoink      Yes     Catch
326 Grumpig     Yes     Evolve
327 Spinda      Yes     Catch
328 Trapinch    Yes     Catch
329 Vibrava     Yes     Evolve
330 Flygon      Yes     Evolve
331 Cacnea      Yes     Catch
332 Cacturne    Yes     Evolve
333 Swablu      Yes     Catch
334 Altaria     Yes     Catch,Evolve
335 Zangoose    No      Trade
336 Seviper     Yes     Catch
337 Lunatone    No      Trade
338 Solrock     Yes     Catch
339 Barboach    Yes     Catch
340 Whiscash    Yes     Catch,Evolve
341 Corphish    Yes     Catch
342 Crawdaunt   Yes     Evolve
343 Baltoy      Yes     Catch
344 Claydol     Yes     Catch,Evolve
345 Lileep      Yes     Fossil
346 Cradily     Yes     Evolve
347 Anorith     Yes     Fossil
348 Armaldo     Yes     Evolve
349 Feebas      Yes     Catch
350 Milotic     Yes     Evolve (High Beauty Level Up)
351 Castform    Yes     Story Reward
352 Kecleon     Yes     Catch
353 Shuppet     Yes     Catch
354 Banette     Yes     Catch
355 Duskull     Yes     Catch
356 Dusclops    Yes     Evolve
357 Tropius     Yes     Catch
358 Chimecho    Yes     Catch
359 Absol       Yes     Catch
360 Wynaut      Yes     Hatch Gift Egg
361 Snorunt     Yes     Catch
362 Glalie      Yes     Evolve
363 Spheal      Yes     Catch
364 Sealeo      Yes     Evolve
365 Walrein     Yes     Evolve
366 Clamperl    Yes     Catch
367 Huntail     No      Trade Evo
368 Gorebyss    No      Trade Evo
369 Relicanth   Yes     Catch
370 Luvdisc     Yes     Catch
371 Bagon       Yes     Catch
372 Shelgon     Yes     Evolve
373 Salamence   Yes     Evolve
374 Beldum      Yes     Story Reward
375 Metang      Yes     Evolve
376 Metagross   Yes     Evolve
377 Regirock    Yes     Catch
378 Regice      Yes     Catch
379 Registeel   Yes     Catch
380 Latias      Yes     Catch Roaming (Only one, other is event)
381 Latios      No      Catch Roaming (Only one, other is event)
382 Kyogre      Yes     Catch
383 Groudon     Yes     Catch
384 Rayquaza    Yes     Catch
385 Jirachi     No      Event
386 Deoxys      No      Event
```

#### Data Notes:

- For Pokemon where a choice must be made (Starter Pokemon, Lati@s, only the first Pokemon and its evolutions are listed as 'Yes', so that the totals only count once.
- Not all methods of obtaining a Pokemon are listed, only the most common ones.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 212/386 because in Emerald you only obtain 1 Moon Stone in Meteor Falls and there is only one other option left in RSE games with is repeatable catch or stealing it from Lunatone, who don't live in Emerald but only in Sapphire. So you can get one Delcatty or one Wigglytuff but no both.

Comment: Can someone explain why this answer has been downvoted? I assume it's because it's incorrect, but I would appreciate an explanation so I could understand what mistake Starapto2000 made.

Comment: He's incorrect because you can clone items in Pokemon Emerald at the Battle Frontier so you can get another moon stone that way.

Comment: So in glitchess way max is 212/386

Comment: I know this is (way) late, I meant to update my post but forgot about it until recently. I have updated my answer with the Moon stone issue. Thanks :)